# Page-Mod of non-HTML files

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to start writing a basic Firefox addon that allows the correct display of markdown files.

Unfortunately I can't even get the first step of the process to work.

I have some basic code:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: [/.*.md/, /.*.markdown/],
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScript: 'window.alert("Page opened");'
});
```

But it doesn't get triggered when opening such a file, locally or from a server.

Even with a simple `include: ['*']` the alert gets triggered on every single page I visit, except when I open a non-HTML file.

So, how if at all possible can I target text files or other non-HTML files, get their content, or write new content into them?

Comment: Content scripts will only trigger when an html document is loaded, so it is not possible to access a non-html page in this way.

Comment: I see. So does that mean I can't do this with an add-on at all or is there another type of script I could use?

Comment: I have a clever idea on how to work around this, I'll test it out and get back to you in a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ( somewhat hacky ) code works for me.

Main.js:

```
var data = require("self").data;
var tabs = require("tabs");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    if (/\.(md|markdown)$/.test(tab.url)) {
        console.log('got markdown!');

        // get the markdown content
        require('request').Request({
            url: tab.url,
            onComplete: function(response) {
                var md = response.text;
                var worker = tab.attach({
                    contentScriptFile: [data.url('markdown.js'), data.url('preview.js')]
                });

                worker.port.emit('init', {raw: response.text});
            }
        }).get();
    }
});

tabs.open('https://raw.github.com/canuckistani/open-in-c9-extension/master/README.md');
```

preview.js:

```
self.port.on('init', function(data) {
    unsafeWindow.document.body.innerHTML = markdown.toHTML(data.raw);
});
```

What I'm doing is fetching the raw markdown text in a second http request, processing it with markdown.js, then inserting it into the page. The definitely hacky bit is the second http request.

Here's a working example on builder:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1031582/latest/

Comment: Works like a charm. I would never have thought of that. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: It's a naive implementation though. For example, this code would fail badly for a page like this one: https://github.com/canuckistani/Fatso/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes, I noticed. But unless there is a way to get the actual MIME-type of the requested file I don't see a way to go around that. That's why in the plugin I disabled the default conversion of files unless they are on the local hard drive. By the way if you want to see your snippet in action: [I published a preliminary version](http://codefool.tumblr.com/post/15031277162/browser-addon-markdown-viewer).

Comment: Loic Duros has blogged about implementing nsiContentPolicy in and SDK-based addon, AFAIK this would get you the content type based functionality you'd need: http://lduros.net/posts/blocking-images-and-other-content-mozila-add-sdk-and-nsicontentpolicy/